Equivalence vs modification
Suppose that two processes have the same finite-dimensional distributions. Does there exist a coupling of them such that they are modifications of each other?

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\in T}$ and $Y=(Y_t)_{t\in T}$ be two stochastic processes with the same finite-dimensional distributions. Then they have the same distribution on the $\sigma$-algebra (say $\Sigma$) generated by the algebra of all cylindrical sets.
So, the pair $(X',Y')$ with $X':=X$ and $Y':=X$ is a coupling of $X$ and $Y$ wrt the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$. Moreover, $X'=Y'$ and hence $X'$ and $Y'$ are modifications of each other.
